# Improper integration and boundedness of function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

This question came to my mind when I was following the book of Goldberg on Real Analysis for introduction of improper integrals.

Suppose $f:[a,\infty)$ is a function such that (i) $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ for every $b>a$. (ii) $\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty} \int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ exist.

Does it follow from these two conditions that $f$ is bounded on whole domain $[a,\infty)$?

(I am studying integrals of this kind seriously first time, so this question come to my mind. I do not know example; if there is trivial example, one may put in comment, and then vote for close, that is also fine to me.)

Comment: In fact, there is a counterexample even for continuous $f$. Imagine $f$ as a series of growing triangles centered at each natural number $n$. The triangles grow larger and larger but if they also get narrower. If they get narrower fast enough, the sum of all their areas ($\int_1^\infty f(x)\ dx$) will be finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. Let $f : [1, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} x &\text{ if } x \in \mathbb{N} \\
e^{-x} &\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$ Then, for any $b \geq 1$, $f$ only has a finite number of discontinuities over $[1, b]$; so, of course, $\int_{1}^b f(x)\ dx = \int_{1}^b e^{-x}\ dx$ . Hence, $\int_{1}^\infty f(x)\ dx$ exists and is just $\int_{1}^\infty e^{-x}\ dx$. However, obviously $f$ is not bounded on $\mathbb{N}$.